# Python: iterate over a string containing newlines

Tags: python, string

I have a string separated by newline characters, I need to work with each line individually. I though I would be able to iterate over by using a for loop. However this prints each character individually.

Example:

```
convo = "Bob: Hello \n Sandy: How are you? \n Bob: Confused by a python problem"

for line in convo:
    print(line)

>>> B
>>> o
>>> b
>>> :
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 24):

You can use `str.splitlines`:

```
>>> convo = "Bob: Hello \n Sandy: How are you? \n Bob: Confused by a python problem"
>>> for line in convo.splitlines():
...     print(line)
...
Bob: Hello
 Sandy: How are you?
 Bob: Confused by a python problem
>>>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

> `str.splitlines([keepends])`
>
> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries. This method 
>   uses the universal newlines approach to splitting lines. Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends is given and true.

Answer (score 7):

Split the string by newlines using [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
for line in convo.splitlines():
    print(line)
```

where `splitlines()` uses *universal newlines* to split the string, meaning that it'll support line separator conventions of different platforms.

Demo:

```
>>> convo = "Bob: Hello \n Sandy: How are you? \n Bob: Confused by a python problem"
>>> for line in convo.splitlines():
...     print(line)
... 
Bob: Hello 
 Sandy: How are you? 
 Bob: Confused by a python problem
```